# Error al vincular tabla vba: error 13 en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: vba

Tengo una base de datos llamada *SMP_be.accdb* con un tabla llamada *catareas* en la carpeta *c:\SMP*.
Por otro lado tengo otra base de datos llamaba *vincula.accdb* con una macro que solo ejecuta la función Vincular tablas, esta función vincula la tabla *catareas* de la base de datos *SMP_be.accdb*.
Este es el código:

```
    Function VincularTablas1()
    Dim Td As TableDef
    On Error GoTo ManipularError
    Set Td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef("Catareas", 131072, "Catareas", _
    ";DATABASE=S:\SMP_be.accdb" & " ;PWD=TSJCDMXsmp2021")
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append Td
    
    Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
    Exit Function
    
    ManipularError:
    If Err.Number = 3012 Then MsgBox "Ya existe la tabla", vbInformation, "Error": Exit Function
    If Err.Number = 7874 Then MsgBox "No existe la tabla", vbInformation, "Error": Exit Function
    MsgBox Err.Description & Err.Number, "VincularTablas"
    End Function
```

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Si ejecuto la función con la ruta a una carpeta local (DATABASE=C:\SMP\SMP_be.accdb) en el mismo equipo sí funciona, pero si la ruta es de un unidad de red compartida o de la misma carpeta pero mapeada a otra unidad como por ejemplo (DATABASE=S:\SMP_be.accdb) me manda un error13 en tiempo de ejecución: no coinciden los datos.
Ya revisé permisos y las carpetas tienen control total.

Comment: En Access, dentro de opciones, Centro de Confianza, ubicaciones de confianza, agrega las rutas que te están dando problemas para que todo funcione.

Comment: De antemano gracias, ya están todas la ubicaciones agregadas en el centro de confianza y esta habilitada la opción de Permitir ubicaciones de confianza que estén en la red. Pero no funciona.

Comment: ¿Qué línea te da el error? ¿La del set o la del append? ¿Has probado a usar el mapeo en la unidad en red? Me refiero a que en vez de usar una ruta tipo `s:/carpeta/archivo` sea una tipo `//servidor/carpeta/archivo`

Comment: Hola, la línea que da el error es la del append. ya probé con una unidad mapeada s: ,también probé directo al servidor //servidor y también probé con el comando subst del sistema operativo para mapear una unidad del disco local a una unidad S:  . y solo funciona cuando pongo c:\.

Comment: Pues en ese caso ya me quedo sin ideas. Deberíamos descartar que es cosa de permisos. Ya leí que los miraste pero prueba a ejecutar una macro que simplemente abra un archivo o lo copie a otra ubicación que esté en la ruta mapeada, a ver si te deja. Si te da error, es cosa de permisos/rutas.

Comment: Ya probé copiar y mover archivos y todo funciona bien. ya no se por donde mas buscar. Creo que es algo con el sistema operativo pues antes funciona bien pero nos cambiaron los equipos y ya no funciono. Sigue siendo Windows 10 y Access 2016 pero algo cambio.